# Error loading "Event processing" page

Tags: cumulocity

I have an error trying to open the "Event processing" page, I've got the following error message:

> Error creating bean with name
>   'scopedTarget.ePServiceProviderFactoryBean' defined in Invocation of
>   init method failed; nested exception is Error initializing: Home
>   directory '/tmp/esperha-storage' does not exist as obtained from
>   environment property 'espertech.esperha.home' : Error initializing:
>   Home directory '/tmp/esperha-storage' does not exist as obtained from
>   environment property 'espertech.esperha.home'

Is there something I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because of a Cumulocity update, the problem was resolved.